# Proof that sum of k-eigenvalues is convex

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, matrix-analysis

I saw a post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98367/a-sum-of-eigenvalues that said

> It is well-known that $\sum^{r}_{i = 1} \lambda_{i}(X)$ is convex.

and I saw an explanation in [Boyd and Vandenberghe - "Convex Optimization"](http://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf), question 3.26(a) that said

> $$\sum^{k}_{i = 1} \lambda_{i}(X) = \sup\{\operatorname{tr}(V^{T}XV) \mid V^{T}V = I\}.$$
>
> The variational characterization shows that $f$ is the pointwise supremum
> of a family of linear functions $\operatorname{tr}(V^{T}XV )$

is an explanation for why it is convex.

But I don't really understand how the sup is the sum of the first $k$ eigenvalues and how that makes it convex.

Comment: What is, perhaps, missing is that $V$ is a $n\times k$ matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The supremum of any family of convex functions is convex. ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363996/convexity-of-supremum-of-convex-functions))

Every linear function is convex.

Hence the supremum of a family of linear functions is convex.

**Edit:**
To prove the supremum identity first note that for $V \in \mathbb R^{n \times k}$ with $V^TV=I$
\begin{align}
\textrm{tr}(V^TXV) &= \textrm{tr}(XVV^T)\\
&\le \lambda(X)^T \lambda(V V^T)
\end{align}
Now since $(VV^T)^2 = VV^T$ the only eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$. Also note that
$$\textrm{tr}(VV^T) = \textrm{tr}(V^TV) = k$$
Hence $VV^T$ has $k$ eigenvalues that are 1 and the rest are zero.
Combining this with the previous inequality yields, and noting that any sum of $k$ eigenvalues is less than the sum of the $k$ largest eigenvalues yields
$$\textrm{tr}(V^TXV) \le \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i(X)$$.

Taking $$V = [v_1, \ldots v_k]$$ where $v_j$ is the normalised eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_j(X)$ achieves the supremum.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the sup of any family of convex functions is convex, I just don't understand by the sup is the first k eigenvalues

Comment: Does this also mean that $f(x) = \sum^{k}_{i} \lambda_{i}(g(x))$ is also convex

Comment: No, take $g(x) = -x^2$ and $n=1$. The sup identity still holds but the family of functions need not be convex.