# Why is pointwise maximum a convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

It seems like if you have a family of function

$$g = \{a(x), \: b(x), \: c(x), \:d(x)\}$$

$$\text{given} \:\: f(x):= max(g),$$

$$\text{if} \: f(1) = a(1), \: f(2) = b(2), \: f(3) = c(3), \: f(4) = d(4) $$

$f\:$ have a possibility of not being continous

Thus the epigraph is not a convex set, am I misunderstanding something?

Edit: I am assuming $a, b, c, d$ to be all convex, but they have different domains that don't overlap

Comment: Which assumptions do you have about the convexity and/or continuity of $a, b, c, d$?

Comment: I am assuming a, b, c, d to be all convex, however 'a' might have different domain than 'b'

Comment: By convention, a convex function is $+\infty$ outside its domain. (This is to ensure that the maximum of convex functions is convex.)

Comment: The epigraph of the $\max$ is the intersection of the epigraphs, hence $f$ must be convex (and continuous on the relative interior of its domain).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I think I get the intuition now, thanks

Comment: See related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402919/pointwise-supremum-of-a-convex-function-collection