# Is pointwise maximum of affine functions convex and continuous on a compact set $K$

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis

Actually, I've already asked [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012186/is-pointwise-maximum-of-countable-family-of-continuous-functions-continuous?noredirect=1#comment8281449_4012186) but I specified my question here.

Consider a max-affine function $f:K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \max_{i \in I}f_i(x)$ where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact set and $f_i(x) = a_i^T x + b_i, \forall i \in I$ are affine functions.

1. (Assumption) Suppose that $a_i$ and $b_i$ are bounded by $M > 0$ for all $i \in I$.
2. (Statement) The max-affine function $f$ is continuous on $K$.

(Proof) Since the max-affine function $f$ is convex (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287619/prove-the-supremum-of-the-set-of-affine-functions-is-convex)) and (Assumption) is assumed,
$f$ is a proper convex function on $K$.
Furthermore, $dom(f) = \mathbb{R}^n$ in this case. By Theorem 10.4 in [R.T. Rockafella, "Convex Analysis"](https://books.google.co.kr/books?hl=ko&lr=&id=GV6YDwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=convex+analysis+rockafellar&ots=OGTlwosHk-&sig=A084FxkFZEPH6hw10XJYK7V5kQU#v=onepage&q=convex%20analysis%20rockafellar&f=false), a proper convex function in $ri(dom(f))$ is continuous, it concludes the statement.

I wonder if 1) the proof is correct, 2) the assumption is necessary to make sure that $f$ is proper, and 3) this holds even if $I$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The proof is correct, although for the sake of argument you should clarify what $ri(dom(f))$ is in this case.
2. Yes, you need this assumption. It is automatically satisfied when $I$ is finite. When $I$ is not finite and you do not make this assumption, you could take $a_i=i$ resulting in $\sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} f_i(x) = \infty$. Bounded should be in absolute sense, so $|a_i|\leq M$ and $|b_i|\leq M$.
3. When $I$ is uncountable you may need $\sup$ instead of $\max$, but the proof is still valid.

Comment: "you may need $\inf$ instead of $\max$" ... You may even need $\sup$.

Comment: @GEdgar haha, thank you